# How can I change a user agent string programmatically?

Tags: python

I want to write a program that changes the HTTP headers in my requests that are sent by my web-browser. I believe it can be done with a proxy server. So, I'd like to write a proxy server.

How can I do this in Python?

Comment: Apache 2 have a HTTP Proxy module, I don't know if it can modify the headers though. I would guess there is some sort of support though.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use an existing proxy such as [Charles HTTP Proxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com/)?  It has the ability to rewrite headers and do all sorts of cool stuff to requests and responses.

Comment: Sweet, this'll come in handy at work. Using Apache atm. but it's a bit cumbersome sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://proxies.xhaus.com/) is a list of HTTP proxies in python.